# iPad 3 problem in updating to iOS7

Tags: ios, ipad

my software update is iOS8.2 but i don't like it because it took a lot of memory 1.3GB but what i want is just iOS7 not iOS8, how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Apple isn't signing iOS 7 any more, so this isn't possible.